# Как добавить нужное ПО в дистрибутив Linux?

Tags: ubuntu

Допустим есть официальный образ Ubuntu Server 16.04. Мне нужно добавить в него ПО к примеру Zabbix agent, т.е. сделать так, чтобы после установки системы я мог сразу запустить zabbix agent.

Comment: Рассмотрите вариант ставить его через систему конфигурирования вроде Ansible в автоматическом режиме.

Comment: Это делается для работы внутри организации или это выездной вариант?

Comment: Внутри организации, я бы хотел понять принцип работы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ubuntu Customization Kit](https://habrahabr.ru/post/77331/) - самый простой вариант, будет готовый установщик из оригинального образа.

Запустится мастер, в нем можно открыть Синаптик и установить пакеты прямо в лайф образ. Потом можно сразу подправить конфигурационные файлы.

Перебор установочного диска также [возможен вручную, тут есть в документации](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)

Раньше я делал скрипт, который просто запускал после установки. Ansible поможет запустить один скрипт на сотне устройств.